# GitHub Questions?

Tags: support, scope

Something crazy weird just happened to me on GitHub yesterday. I'm not sure if I can understand what exactly happened; the audit trail looks ... self-incriminating.

Is this the right place to ask GitHub-related questions?

Answer (score 9):

If what you're asking is about interacting with GitHub from the command line `git`, the GitHub application for Windows or Mac, or more generally, doing stuff with Git, then it'd be on topic here.

However, Git questions may also be asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). It's one of these "tools that programmers use", so [you'd be fine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146224/git-questions-migrated-to-super-user) to ask there as well. In fact, Git questions might get better exposure on Stack Overflow than here.

If your question only concerns operating GitHub's web interface, then [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) has got you covered. Might also be on-topic for Stack Overflow, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Just for a quick comparison: We have about 600 questions about Git, while Stack Overflow has 22,000 on it.

Comment: Didn't know it was that much of a difference. Thanks for the numbers, Simon!

Comment: If you look at it, Git doesn't really have much use beyond the scope of code and programming (ie. SO; besides novelty uses)